# Flutter Firebase Notify Admin On New Request

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am learning flutter /firebase and trying to explore a functionality where I can get an email on a new document created in a specific collection. Is it possible in flutter or firebase?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Cloud Firestore Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events). These Triggers are easy to set up with [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started)

The code below is a function that gets triggered when a new document is created inside an example collection of `Users`. Once triggered, we can extract the user name and email (that comes from the request to create a new user), and use [Nodemailer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer) to send a custom email.

`{your_email}` and `{your_password}` represent the email account that is sending this email.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
import * as nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    priority: 'high',
    auth: {
        user: '{your_email}',
        pass: '{your_password}',
    },
});

export const onCreateUserTrigger = functions.firestore
  .document('Users/{userId}')
  .onWrite((snap, context) => { 

    const userEmail = snap.data().email;
    // this is the email we send to but you can make this any email: 
    // userEmail = 'admin@gmail.com';
    const userName = snap.data().name;
    const userId = context.params.userId;

    // send a mail
    const htmlText = `<p>Hello ${userName},  </p>
    <p> This is a notification about... </p>
    `;
    const mailOptions = {
        from: "{your_name} <{your_email}>",
        to: userEmail,
        subject: "Notification",
        html: htmlText,
    };
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);

 });
```

If you want a function that gets triggered for any write (create and edit) to the `Users` collection you can change the firestore function to `onWrite`:

```
export const onWriteUserTrigger = functions.firestore
  .document('Users/{userId}')
  .onWrite((snap, context) => { 

   // send email
 });
```